# How to customize related list order in Custom VF page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, case, related-list

I have written custom VF page on CASE object to show custom object as related list to the CASE. I could able to do that but I need to show at the top of all other CASE's standard related list. Im only trying to show ObjA's related list at the top of case standard related list. if you see the below picture .. it's a override case custom VIEW page... I'm trying to bring that Obj A at the bottom to top of Time Trackings related list..

**Extension**

```
public class Relatedlist {
    Private List<ObJ_A__c> obja;
    private Case cse;
    public RelatedList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.cse = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    }
    Public List<Obj_A__c> getObjA() {
        Case cse = [Select id, Contact.id, CaseNumber from Case WHERE id = : cse.id];
        if(cse.Contact == null) return null;
        obja = [Select Name, User__c, XXXX__c, XXXX__c, from Obj_A__c WHERE User__c = :cse.Contact.id];
        return obja;
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="Relatedlist" sidebar="true">
    <style>
    .fewerMore { display: none;}
    </style>
    <apex:tabPanel selectedTab="Knowledge"> </apex:tabPanel>
    <chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!Case.Id}" />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages > </apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:detail relatedList="true" inlineEdit="true" > </apex:detail>  
        <apex:pageblock id="CustomList"  title="ObjA"  >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!obja}" var="l" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(obja))}">
                <apex:column value="{!l.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!l.User__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!l.XXXXXX__c}"/>                                   
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!(ISNULL(lcnse))}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
            </apex:pageblock>                             
    </apex:form>                                                        
</apex:page>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Page Screenshot]

Comment: This is a bit unclear, showing more context would be helpful

Comment: @Gidy If you are querying for the list `objA` you can just modify your `SOQL` to add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: If you want to move the apex-created related list `CustomList` ahead of the related lists defined in the page Layout (because you are using `apex:detail relatedList="true"` , you're going to need jQuery to manipulate the DOM after page load.

Comment: @Gidy For future reference, please [edit] your post when you have content to add, instead of tossing it in the comments

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep `apex:detail`, two options, neither pretty:

**Option 1**

Requires jQuery DOM manipulation, you'll need to hack into the VF page using Firebug or its ilk to see the structure and use jQuery methods to `move` a DOM tag (and its children) representing your custom RL ahead of the DOM tag for the first OOB related list. This is certainly doable as I have done this before swapping pageBlockSections around based on data values.

Option 1 has issues:

1. It has to work for both inline edit and otherwise
2. It is fragile as it depends on how SFDC renders into DOM the related lists
3. It has to be tested for Lightning as well as Classic

**Option 2**

Don't use the OOB related lists on `apex:detail` but instead do:

```
<apex:detail relatedList="false" ...>
<your custom related list goes here>
<apex:relatedList ... list for RL 1>
<apex:relatedList ... list for RL 2>
<apex:relatedList ... list for RL 3>
```

Option 2 has all sorts of issues:

1. Not all OOB related lists can be shown - notably field history. You then need to use a custom component (Google it) for the field history RL. Some relatedLists even have bugs in them like `ServiceContracts`
2. You lose the quick links / mini hovers normally seen at the top of `apex:detail`. Reconstructing them requires javascript hacks to call internal SFDC javascript methods

So, you end up with a more complex page that is also semi-fragile if you try to reproduce the quick links/mini-hovers

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to reorder the records in the list**

You need to modify this line in your extension:

```
obja = [
    SELECT Name, User__c, XXXX__c, XXXX__c
    FROM Obj_A__c WHERE User__c = :cse.Contact.id
];
```

You have some confusing naming, what with a `User__c` lookup matching a `ContactId`, but that's beside the point. You need to add an `ORDER BY` [clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm). Here is one example:

```
SELECT Name FROM Obj_A__c WHERE User__c = cse.ContactId ORDER BY Name DESC
```

---

**If you want the list above the detail**

To place the list above the entire `detail` view, you just need to reorder the tags.

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    ...
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:detail />
```

---

**If you want to insert the list between Case History and Related Cases**

What you want to accomplish is not possible, and if you find a way it's going to involve some serious hacking.

Comment: Adrian - I think OP wants his custom apex-related list to appear before the apex:detail - generated related lists when viewed from top to bottom

Comment: @cropredy Ah, upon rereading it looks like he wants it in between related lists on the `detail`. Not possible then.

Comment: well, possible with jQuery DOM rearranging after page load; I've done this before (kind of) by rearranging pageblocksections and I don't see why it couldn't be done (fragile, yes, subject-to-sfdc-breakage, yes) here.

Comment: @cropredy But isn't the `detail` inside an `iframe`? Can you really move the `DOM` in that way?

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's not in an `iframe` and that assumption was mistaken.

Comment: @cropredy ... Exactly .. if you see at the case record image that posted.. in that I want "Obj A" related list [at the bottom] to appear above the "Time Tracking" related list ...

Comment: @Gidy -- as I thought - solution requires jQuery DOM manipulation, you'll need to hack into the VF page using Firebug or its ilk to see the structure and figure out how to `move` a DOM tag (and its children) representing your custom RL ahead of the DOM tag for the first OOB related list